# Accessing features via ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I try to use ArcPy to accessing the features of a shapefile. I tried to use a searcheCursor, like that:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Points, ["SHAPE@XY"])
for row in cursor:
    x, y = row[0]
    print "Origin"
    print("{0}, {1}".format(x, y))
    row = cursor.next()
    x, y = row[0]
    print "End"
    print("{0}, {1}".format(x, y))
```

It's just a example. In the first loop I want to use feature 1 and 2, in the second feature 2 and 3. But my problem is that I can't do the access by the row-index.

Is there a possibility to do what I want?

Comment: Related: [Move the cursor backward - opposite of row = rows.next()](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/63495/753)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there isn’t any way to do this directly.

But you can load your FeatureClass in a list and access features from it. For loading a FeatureClass in a list, you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869473/loading-a-feature-class-in-a-list-using-arcpy-strange-behaviour-of-searchcurso

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple windowing function:

```
def window_func(iterator, window_size=2):
    window = []
    for item in iterator:
        window.append(item)
        if len(window) >= window_size:
            yield tuple(window)
            window = window[1:]

for row1, row2 in window_func(arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Points, ["SHAPE@XY"])):
    print row1, row2
```